# javaerror while installing the hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I want to install Hive and hadoop on my ubuntu.I followed [this article](http://www.hackido.com/2010/05/install-hadoop-and-hive-on-ubuntu-lucid.html) all of things seems good but the end step when I write this command an error about Java appear like this:

**/home/babak/Downloads/hadoop/bin/../bin hadoop: row 258:/usr/lib/j2sdk1.5-sun/bin/java: file or Folder not found**

what should i do to solve this problem?

Comment: Does the file `/usr/lib/j2sdk1.5-sun/bin/java` exist on the local file system?. If not then you need to re-configure your `$HADOOP_HOME/conf/hadoop-env.sh` to point to the location of your java installation

Comment: Can you also link to the article you are following

Comment: Sorry I forgot it,I did not find this java file and i dont know where it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find where on your machine java is installed:

```
which java
```

and then from there follow any symlinks or wrapper scripts to the actual location of the java executable.

An easier way to do this is to run the file indexer and then locate the file (here i use the jps executable, which is in the same folder as java:

```
#> sudo updatedb
#> locate jps
```

Whatever you get back, trim off the bin/jps suffix, and that's your JAVA_HOME value. If you can't find the executable, than you'll need to install java

Comment: Thank you very much chris:If I run the first command the result is: **/usr/bin/java** the second part of your answer,I guess I didn't understand correctly but I run the commands you mentioned but no changes :(  ( sorry I 'm new in this field)

Comment: What was the output of `locate jps`?

Comment: :Thank you for your hint you saved me :)

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop requires Java version 1.6 or higher. It seems like hadoop is looking for Java 1.5. Also, make sure the variable HADOOP_HOME is set in file /conf/hadoop-env.sh

I have a line like the following in mine:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/
```